# Deploy ASP.NET Core on a cheap Ubuntu VPS

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, web-deployment, vps

I have a limited Ubuntu VPS(512MB RAM, 20GB Hard Drive) and limited bandwidth, Docker Containers are about 1 or 2 GB.
Is there a way to optimize these images for deployment in reasonable amount of time?

Comment: a) define reasonable, b) what issue are you having, precisely?

Comment: I can't upload images in gigabytes to docker hub

Comment: What did you try? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=optimise+docker+container&oq=optimise+docker+container&aqs=chrome..69i57.3088j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I tried just building Docker images for my web app. some tutorial about optimizing size don't allow significant gain in size.

Comment: I just figured out that official docker image for ms sql server, can not be implemented on 512MB memory VPS.